# call Telegram.api in browser (Windows): sendPhoto

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I am using Telegram to send pictures from a IP-cam.
This can be done on raspberry-PI like this:

curl -s -X POST "https://api.telegram.org/bot123456789:yourcode/sendPhoto" -F chat_id=123456789 -F photo="@/volume1/Data/temp/picture.jpeg"

Explanation: the picture is in the folder "/volume1/Data/temp" the name is "picture.jpeg"

I want to do the same on Windows and I constantly get message "{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: Wrong persistent file_id specified: contains wrong characters or has wrong length"}"

This is exactly (exact for the bot and yourcode and chatid) what I transmit in the address of Google Chrome:

> https://api.telegram.org/bot123456789:yourcode/sendPhoto?chat_id=123456789&photo="@C:/temp/picture.jpeg"

I can assure you the is no problem with autorisation (filling in file:///C:/temp/picture.jpeg in the browser shows me the picture).
And I have tried al kinds of variantions (with and without @, with and without ", etc. etc.). I cannot get it working.

And it works with sending text:

...../sendMessage?chat_id=123456789&text=”hello”

result is that I get the message "hello" and this in the browser: {"ok":true,"result":{"message_id" ......

I am sure I am close but do not know how to define exactly the "picture".

So the questions is: what is the exact way to transmit a picture with Telegram through a Windows browser using api.telegram.org? Please provide an example that is working.

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

When you transmit that url in chrome (or any other browser) you are actually using "GET" method than can be used for send image with its "file_id".

But when you want to upload a file from your pc, you should use "POST" method to send it.

On of easiest ways is using a HTML form.

For an example:

```
<form action="https://api.telegram.org/bot2222222:AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/sendPhoto" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="text" name="chat_id" value="11111111" />
    <input type="file" name="photo"  />
    <input type="submit" value="send" />

</form>
```

**Edit:**

Also if you want to do it from command line you can use windows version of cUrl. You can download it from this link:
[Windows cUrl](https://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=bin&os=Win64&flav=-&ver=*&cpu=x86_64)

or use Invoke-RestMethod in windows powershell.
example command:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -InFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I transmit this HTML Form on my Windows-PC so the picture is send through Telegram?

Comment: @JohnB Just save it in html format and open it with your browser. Then you see a brows bottom. Press it and brows your photo. Then press send bottom.

Comment: Okay; this I got working. Thanks so far. The " but"  is that I want to use it in the command-line (to get this running automatically: eg to send every hour a picture). I can do i now manually; in Linux the one curl-command was enough. Do you know perhaps a solution for this?

Comment: I think the easiest way for you is using windows version of cUrl. you can find it here: [Windows cUrl](https://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=bin&os=Win64&flav=-&ver=*&cpu=x86_64)